# Facebook API in Python error: Latitude and longitude must be in the signed decimal degree format, e.g. 37.484531,-122.148061

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's Places Search in their API. Whenever I specify the parameters for the center (which takes lat/long pairs in the format XX.XX,-XX.XX), it gives me the error. However, I'm not sure how to format the lat/long coordinates in Python. If I encase the coordinates in brackets, I get the same error. If I don't encase the coordinates in brackets, Python treats it as a syntax error.

Here's what I'm trying to submit:

```
import facebook
token = 'XXXX'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token, version = '2.7')
place = graph.search(type = 'place', q = 'restaurants', center = 
[29.77462,-95.41092], fields = 'name,location,hours,overall_star_rating,rating_count,checkins,description,is_permanently_closed')
```

However, this is what I get back:

```
c:\users\[user]\src\facebook-sdk\facebook\__init__.py in search(self, type, 
**args)
133 
134         args["type"] = type
--> 135         return self.request(self.version + "/search/", args)
136 
137     def get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args):

c:\users\[user]\src\facebook-sdk\facebook\__init__.py in request(self, path, 
args, post_args, files, method)
289 
290         if result and isinstance(result, dict) and result.get("error"):
--> 291             raise GraphAPIError(result)
292         return result
293 

GraphAPIError: (#100) For field 'placesearch': Latitude and longitude must be 
in the signed decimal degree format, e.g. 37.484531,-122.148061
```

How do I get around this error that isn't taking my lat/long coordinates?

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: I've included everything I've coded so far, including the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the issue: coordinates have to be in a string, so the argument should be:

```
center = '29.77462,-95.41092'
```